# how to select what CONTAINS instead of selecting ONLY WHAT IS EQUAL in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that fills a table in my reportviewer that looks like this:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╗
║ SALES  ║ PRODUCTS  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 1 ║ Product A ║
║        ║ Product B ║
║        ║ Product C ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 2 ║ Product D ║
║        ║ Product A ║
║        ║ Product F ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 3 ║ Product B ║
║        ║ Product G ║
║        ║ Product C ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 4 ║ Product A ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝
```

I need to filter the sales, I want to show only the sales that have a specific product, for example: if I want to see only the sales that have the `Product A`, it would have to be the following result:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╗
║ SALES  ║ PRODUCTS  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 1 ║ Product A ║
║        ║ Product B ║
║        ║ Product C ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 2 ║ Product D ║
║        ║ Product A ║
║        ║ Product F ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 4 ║ Product A ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝
```

But the filter I have returns this to me:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╗
║ SALES  ║ PRODUCTS  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ sale 4 ║ Product A ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝
```

this is the filter I have:

```
SELECT cabecalho.ID, cabecalho.NaturezaOperacao, cabecalho.DataEmissao, cabecalho.ValorTotal, NFI.ID_NF, PS.ProductName, NFI.Quantidade, NFI.ValorUnitario
FROM(
SELECT NF.ID, NF.NaturezaOperacao, NF.DataEmissao, NF.ValorTotal
FROM NotaFiscal NF INNER JOIN
    Venda V
ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID INNER JOIN
    Usuario U 
ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
WHERE
    ((U.Descricao = @usuario) OR (@usuario IS NULL)) AND
    (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida)) cabecalho 


                      ======== ANOTHER JOINS =========        

WHERE
    ((U.Descricao = @usuario) OR (@usuario IS NULL)) AND
    (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida) AND
    ((PS.ProductName LIKE '%' + @product + '%') OR (@product IS NULL))
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @ordem = 'value' THEN cabecalho.ValorTotal END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @ordem = 'date' THEN cabecalho.DataEmissao END DESC
```

How i fix it ??

Comment: If you are passing in `'Product A'` and not getting all rows back that match that, then there is clearly something else causing the other rows to be excluded.  Additionally, if you only want to see sales for Product A, why does your desired result have product b,c,d,and f?

Comment: Why you're storing products like that in the first place?

Comment: I want to see all sales that have 'Product A', not sales that only have 'Product A'

Comment: this is just an example

Comment: Edit your question and show the full query.